# How to disable date auto update/correct/adjust in Java?

Tags: java, string, date, validation

Im trying to check the format of the Date.

Implementation: Get Date format `yyyy-MM-dd` then if i input beyond month 12 and day 30 or 31 depend on the month it must show error.

The pattern will work if I manually setup a date in String, but the date must come from Date to String but the Date will auto adjust.

Try the code here: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/

```java
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.ZoneId;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
    import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.time.Instant;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    
    
    class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 11, 33).getTime();  
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        String strDate = formatter.format(date); 
        
          
            
             Pattern dateFrmtPtrn =  Pattern.compile(
                        "((19|20)\\d\\d)"
                                + "-"
                        + "(0?[1-9]|1[012])"
                        + "-"
                        
                        +"(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"
                        );
    Matcher mtch = dateFrmtPtrn.matcher(strDate);
            
            if(mtch.matches(
            )){
                
                System.out.println(strDate);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
          
        }
    }
    //Must Error
    //Output: 2016-01-02
```

The manual with String only.
This will work.

```java
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.ZoneId;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
    import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.time.Instant;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    
    
    class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        
        //  String datey = "2023-12-32";
          String datey = "2023-13-32";
            
             Pattern dateFrmtPtrn =  Pattern.compile(
                        "((19|20)\\d\\d)"
                                + "-"
                        + "(0?[1-9]|1[012])"
                        + "-"
                        
                        +"(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"
                        );
    Matcher mtch = dateFrmtPtrn.matcher(datey);
            
            if(mtch.matches(
            )){
                
                System.out.println(datey);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
          
        }
    }
    
    //working
    //Output: Error
```

Comment: Why are you using `setLenient(true)` when your description indicates you expect non-lenient behaviour? As an aside, stop using the legacy date/time classes and switch to the classes java.time.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I also try to false still will adjust, i update also my post question to `false`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Oky i will switch to  java.time classes

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what `strDate` contains in the first case ?

Comment: Your issue is that `Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 11, 33).getTime();` results in date `2016-01-02` instead of an error. As `2016-01-02` is a valid date, nothing will error after that.

Comment: @jhamon i just try it now its already `adjusted`

Comment: I too strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`, `GregorianCalendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the last in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switched to a `java.time.LocalDate`, you could use the `Exception`s that get thrown when you try to initialize a `LocalDate` with invalid values:

Let's say you just want to create a `LocalDate` with given `int` values for year, month of year and day of month. You could `try` to initialize one and print the error message of the `DateTimeException` thrown.

e.g. the following code will print an error:

```java
try {
    // try to create December 32. 2022
    LocalDate invLocDat = LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 32);
    System.out.println("Created LocalDate: " + invLocDat);
} catch (DateTimeException dte) {
    // print what the exception says
    System.err.println(dte.getMessage());
}
```

The message printed will be

```
Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 32
```

You could find out an invalid month of year, too, e.g. `LocalDate.of(2022, 13, 31)` would cause the above code to print

```
Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 13
```

And a valid input would simply print the `toString()` method of the successfully created `LocalDate`. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` if you want different output.

Comment: this work good.

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of Calendar is to be lenient.

When you write `Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 11, 33).getTime();` you are getting the `Date` value of a lenient calendar, so the 33th day after the 1st of december.

In your code, you set the formatter to be lenient which is useless as the date you want to format is already adjusted.

To avoid that, create a calendar, set it non-lenient and then set the expected date.
But note that in this case the formatter will not return any invalid date as the `Date` object will always be valid.